# Can an employee accompany Permanent Residents moving to Canada?

Tags: canada

We are Permanent Residents of Canada and moving to Canada from Dubai. I am pregnant and would like to bring my maid from Dubai with us. She is a Nepalese passport holder. What visa does she need to accompany us?

Comment: @samvetamodgil Likely a work permit. Have you tried checking via https://www.cic.gc.ca/visit-visiter/en/visas ?

Comment: It looks unlikely but you should read through the information about the [caregiver pilot program](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/caregivers.html).

Comment: If you were coming for a visit bringing her would be likely. But coming permanently you would likely have to prove nobody else could do the job. Or she would have to apply for a work visa or PR on her own merits.